# Can't add more images with <img> to my html file

Tags: image, html, limit

I'm trying to add more `<img>`s to my html, but when I put one more `<img>` to any div - this div turns off, image doesn't show up too.
Is there a limit of number of images inside one html file?

Comment: No, there is not. Please provide link/jsfiddle or some example of code so that we can take a look at your problem :)

Comment: Also, can you explain what "div turns off" means? And how many images are we talking about? Enough to fill the browser's cache allocation, for instance?

Comment: Maybe the size of your image make your HTML load slower and you maybe need to give it more time to load?

Comment: please post the code.. that is the only way we could help you

Comment: I just tried to add images again to existing divs - everything worked this time :/
But when I put new <div> and add <img> to it - </div> tag "becomes red" and appears as a closing tag that not connected to any opening one.

Too bad I can't attach any images yet.

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot somewhere and link to it? Oh, and what editor are you using to create the HTML? I can't recall any of them doing that, and I've used a lot of them.

Comment: You probably have a syntax error somewhere in your html markup. If you want us to help you with it, post what you have and we could look at what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you examine what's happening when you attempt to render your page in the browser. You should be able to view the markup in any browser, although Google Chrome provides a very nifty interface for inspecting page elements (F12 hotkey).